# Visual Studio Intellisense autocomplete on space- how to disable?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

How do I stop VS22 from thinking it knows what I want when I press space?

I have this set:
[image]

And even with this set it tries to tell me what i want to do...

This setting is also greyed out:
[image]

I just want autocomplete when I hit TAB not whenever it decides.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

What you set up doesn't achieve what you want.

I think I understand what application scenario you are referring to. You want to use a class or member that doesn't exist yet, right? Intellisense pops up and tells you "I know you want this", which makes you feel it is very annoying.

A method that allows you to enter spaces normally without automatically completing spaces:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

This will turn on suggestion mode in your situation. Remember to make sure you are in pure english keyboard when you press the above keys:

[image]